# Name of the DU case

Tags: f#

How do I make this test pass by filling out `magic`?

```
type DU =
  | ACaseName
  | BThereCake

let magic (q: Quotation<_>): string =
  // smallest F# code in here?

open Expecto
let subject = magic <@ ACaseName @>
Expect.equal subject "ACaseName" "Should extract the NAME of the DU case"
```

Answer (score 11):

In this case, the following will do:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let magic (q: Expr<_>): string =
  match q with 
  | Patterns.NewUnionCase(case, args) -> case.Name
  | _ -> failwith "Not a union case"

let subject = magic <@ ACaseName @>
```

The question is, what do you want to do when the union case has some arguments. For example:

```
type DU =
  | ACaseName
  | BThereCake of int
```

If you wanted to extract the name from `<@ BThereCake @>` and not just from `<@ BThereCake(12) @>`, then you need to add one more case:

```
let magic (q: Expr<_>): string =
  match q with 
  | DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.NewUnionCase(case, args))
  | Patterns.NewUnionCase(case, args) -> case.Name
  | _ -> failwith "Not a union case"

let subject = magic <@ BThereCake @>
```

Comment: I just want the name without the cases. :)